# Typeerror on rabbitmq admin page

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed rabbitmq and am using it well, but I am getting the following error only on certain PCs. I think it's a version issue, so I reinstalled the version to the latest 3.12.12, deleted cookies, and restarted rabbitmq several times, but it still happens. Does anyone know what could be the cause?

TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined(reading'name') TypeError:cannot read properties of undefined (reading'name')at Array.process(eval at compile (http://localhost:15672/js/ejs-1.0.min.js:1:6654), :246:139) at EJS.render (http://localhost:15672/js/ejs-1.0.min.js:1:1885) at format(http://localhost:!5672/js/main.js:1156:21) at http://localhost:15672/js/main.js:461:24 at with_reqs(http://localhost:15672/js/main.js:1138:9) at http://localhost:15672/js/main.js:1134:17 at req.onreadystatechange(http://localhost:15672/js/main.js:1215:17)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it turned out it was because of browser cookies from previous RabbitMQ versions. Have you tried with incognito browser mode ?

Comment: It was a test server, so I couldn't confirm it because a complete wipe and reinstall didn't reproduce it anymore, but I'll try that method if I see the same thing again! Thanks!